# Android notification custom view layout is different on another device

Tags: android

I've created a notification out of custom view.
The problem is that it looks fine on a Nexus 5X device but it looks broken on Samsung Galaxy S4 device.
My notification contains Hebrew content, so it needs to be with a right-to-left direction (meaning buttons are on the left and text is on the right).

This is what the notification looks like on the Nexus 5X device (just like I meant it to look):
[image: notification on nexus 5x]

This is what the notification looks like on the Samsung Galaxy S4 device:
[image: notification on Samsung Galaxy S4]

As you can see, the notification on the Galaxy S4 is differently (the buttons on the right, the text indentation is off and so on)

I have to say that most of the app looks fine on both of the devices. 
This is the only thing that set the two apart.
In addition, both of the devices are set to the same language and locale.

This is the code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
     android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
    android:layoutDirection="locale">


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:text="סבבה"
        android:layout_height="227dp"
        android:id="@+id/attendButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-72dip" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:text="לא טוב"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:id="@+id/declineButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-7dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event Name"
            android:tag="event"
            android:id="@+id/eventName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="EventTime"
            android:id="@+id/eventTimeTxt"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="right"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="EventDayOfWeek"
                android:id="@+id/eventDayOfTheWeekTxt"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="yesFromInvited"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/yesFromInvitedTxt"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I'm thinking that the location of the text and the buttons in the notification might have something to do with the fact that the content is in Hebrew (Right-to-Left language).

I have tried it on two different Galaxsy S4 devices, both of them have Android 5.0.1, and it looks the same in both of them. All of the devices are the same language and locale.

What can I do in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't refer to the fact that your design not following the design recommendation for Notification (as you can read [here](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html)).

What I will say is that, regarding the fact that you declared that your content will be Hebrew, you just didn't design your xml attributes properly. You should use:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

And also make sure to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the `Application` tag in the manifest.

And your buttons need to be inserted at the end of the root `LinearLayout`, not in the start.
Your xml should be something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="event"
        android:text="שם האירוע"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="21sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventTimeTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="EventTime"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventDayOfTheWeekTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EventDayOfWeek"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yesFromInvitedTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="yesFromInvited"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/attendButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="227dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-72dip"
    android:text="סבבה"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-7dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-80dip"
    android:text="לא טוב"/>
```

Comment: The buttons should be on the left, and putting them in the end of the root like here makes them move to the right. Also, I have already tried the "rtl" thing, it didn't help.

Comment: It may depend on the `Locale` definition in the device, but when you define the direction to be RTL, it's means you need to put your buttons at the end. What is the Locale languages in both devices?

Comment: The locale languages in the Nexus 5X are Hebrew (as the main language) and English (as the secondary language), as set on the Language prefrences in the setting app.

The locale language in the Galaxsy S4 is only Hebrew.

Comment: Did you added `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your `Application` tag in the manifest?

Comment: No, I didn't know about it... I have just added it and it works! thanks! You can write it as an answer.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your samsung device RTL is getting applied, its possible because samsung customize android framework.

Here I think you should disable RTL by setting `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` property in XML.

Comment: It didn't help. The notification stays the same in the S4.

Answer (score 0):

First, open the Galaxy S4's Developer Options page from the Android Settings menu and check "Force RTL layout direction". Check if the notification changes in any way - if it does, it means that the device does not correctly recognize the layout as being RTL in the first place.

Alternatively, you will need to check whether your device actually supports RTL locales. Keep in mind that a locale is not just `<language>_<country>`, but also has the notion of scripts, variants and extensions. Easiest way to check this:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if(config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
//in Right To Left layout
}
```

Apart from that, when you create layouts that are meant to work with RTL locales, avoid using `android:gravity="right"` or `android:gravity="left"`. Use `end` and `start` instead.

Comment: I have tried to force RTL and try again. It didn't help. After it, I have tried to to check if the device supports RTL, and it does.